# Fonts in Netbeans smaller than desired

Tags: netbeans, fonts

My Netbeans 7.4 claims, it uses `Courier New 18pt` font:

[image]

However, when I set my Notepad++ (and *any* other piece of software on my Windows 7) to **the very same typefaces and font size**:

[image]

Font clearly looks much bigger.

Can someone enlighten me, what am I missing? How can two programs claim that they use the very same font for text display and display that text it two different heights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have you unconsciously made zoom. Try Alt + Mouse Wheel or defined there: 
https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/scroll_in_netbeans_editor_to